# SCCM Updating Package source and Rerun Behaviour

Tags: sccm

I have a package which contains a login script which I update from time to time.

I do some changes in the script then I do a "Update Distribution Points", which increments the "Source version" of the package.

In the adverisement I have set the schedule as a Mandantory assignment and "As soon as Possible".
The "Program rerun behavior" is set to "Rerun if failed previous attempt".

I only want the Package program to rerun when the source version has changed.

The problem is that the program will not rerun beacause it has previously ran the package with sucess even though the source version has changed.

But then if I set rerun behaivor to "Always rerun", will it rerun everytime the client checks for updates OR only when the source version has changed?

We use SCCM 2007 SP2 R2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither, you want to set it to Always rerun Program - but doing so will not do anything until you add another mandatory assignment. Each time you make a change to the script and you want it to run again, you'll want\need to add another mandatory assignment. Depending how often you modify the script, perhaps running the script on a schedule in SCCM and putting a conditional into the script itself might work better for you (aka be less work). i.e. check for a flag file or something - depending on what this script is doing for you.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Mandatory assignment and you will have the option to re-run the advertisement when you right click on the advertisement in question, simple.